# limit a view to the left/right of center in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to specify that a view should lie strictly to the left of the center (or strictly to the right of the center)? I have two textviews, one for LOGIN and one for REGISTER. I have them as children of RelativeLayout. No matter what I do I can't get them to behave. The one configuration that works in the `Graphical Layout` of eclipse, only shows the registration button on a real device. Here it is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bckg"
    android:padding="10dip"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity" >
...

<View
        android:id="@+id/center_btns"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_fields"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_fields"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center_btns"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bkg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_fields"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center_btns"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bkg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="register"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I set them as children of a horizontal linearLayout, how do I specify their relationship to get it to work? I already tried that and no avail.

Comment: funny thing, though: I always thought what I see in the `Graphical Layout` is what I can on a real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I could post this as a comment but I don't quite have the rep... Anyway, to clarify, do you want the items to be right next to each other on the same line? If so the LinearLayout should work just fine...

```
<LinearLayout
    ...android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
/>
```

Should work just fine. If not you may try playing with weights depending on which one you want to take up more space. For weights to work you will need to see the width of both to fill_parent.